# Grep regex - select text between tag BUT text contains string AND stop at first end-tag

Tags: regex, grep

The command I use:

```
grep -oP '(?s)opentag.*?myString.*?closetag' myFile
```

This is working fine when the text 'myString' is found between the tags.
 For this case :

```
opentag
  myString
closetag
```

the result is:

```
myString
```

But when 'myString' is not found, grep will consider the next 'closetag'. Exemple :

```
opentag
closetag
  myString
closetag
```

the result is:

```
closetag
  myString
```

Is there any way to stop the parsing at the first 'closetab' read ?
In this case there won't be any results.

I can do it by coding a parser but not the time nor the motivation.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `negative lookahead` here.

```
(?s)opentag((?!(?:open|close)tag).)*myString((?!(?:open|close)tag).)*closetag
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eX9gK2/6

Comment: This construct is called *tempered greedy token*.

Answer (score 1):

Good grief, just use awk with a flag to indicate when you're inside the open/close block:

```
awk '/opentag/{f=1} f&&/myString/; /closetag/{f=0}' file
```

With your examples:

```
$ cat file1
opentag
  myString
closetag
$
$ awk '/opentag/{f=1} f&&/myString/; /closetag/{f=0}' file1
  myString
$

$ cat file2
opentag
closetag
  myString
closetag
$
$ awk '/opentag/{f=1} f&&/myString/; /closetag/{f=0}' file2
$
```

When it's a simple problem to state it should be a simple problem to solve!

Comment: I should probably use AWK more often ! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: When you're doing anything that involves searching across multiple input lines you should be using awk instead of sed or grep for simplicity, clarity, robustness, maintainability, and just about every other desirable attribute of software. FWIW I recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.